# Printf not working with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

Hi i am new to the programing and for example in my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
   int a;
   printf("Write a number: ");
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("Your written number was: %d", a);
   return 0;
}
```

`Printf` does not write "write a number" in console when i start the program but only after i already inserted the number and pressed enter.
I have already done some research and found out for this code:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

when i paste this into my program it works as it should but i am wondering why do i have to do that?

Comment: Add linefeed "\n" to your printf lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i paste this into my program it works as it should but i am
>   wondering why do i have to do that?

It's because `printf()` is usually line-buffered when attached to a terminal. So disabling the buffering with the call to `setvbuf()` makes stdio library to not buffer at all.

You can also use `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()` call to flush out the buffered output. The same can be done with `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` as well.

---

You can also add a `\n` at the end of `printf()` statement to force the flushing. But this will work only if the output goes to a terminal device.

For example, if you do (on a unix-like system):

```
./a.out > output_file
```

then the `\n` will not flush the buffer.

Out of the two options (`setbuf()` and `fflush()`),`fflush(stdout);` is probably the better option in most cases. Since disabling the buffering completely can have negative impact on performance (which is the primary reason for buffering in the first place) whereas `fflush()` can be judiciously used at the right place when you think it's necessary.

Comment: But why ist that code written in my book i am learning from. Also when i looked up on the internet, this code wastn inclued. @I3x

Comment: @ŽigaGazvoda Prabably the author isn't aware of this or ignored it here and explained it elsewhere in the book or simply forgot to mention it. I can only guess. This is a standard behaviour and nothing unexpected/unusual about it.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` has a buffer. It is a mechanism to make code run faster by not having to switch between the user context and the kernel context. To get over this you can tell the code to flush the buffer - i.e. send it to the operating system. This can be done by

```
fflush(stdout);
```

After a `printf`. If the `printf` contains a new line this is done automatically.

Comment: But what did you mean by "If the printf contains a new line this is done automatically".

Answer (score 0):

Add linefeed "\n" to your printf lines like so:

```
printf("Write a number: \n");
```

Comment: am sorry what does that mean?

Comment: I think you need to find a good beginner book and work through it

Answer (score 0):

You probably want \n in each of those printf statements.